# How can change TextFormField line color?

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

How can change the color of TextFormField that is black like below?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
    ),
  ),
),
```